# How to add redux to two functional components in the same file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add `redux` to two functional components, namely buttons, that reside in the same file. Here's the code:

```
export function FeedbackButton(props) {
  return (
    <Button
      icon={"comment"}
      minimal={true}
      text={"Feedback?"}
      onClick={() => props.toggleFeedback()}
    />
  );
}

export function HelpButton(props) {
  return (
    <Button icon={"help"} minimal={true} onClick={() => props.toggleHelp()} />
  );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    toggleFeedback: () => dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_FEEDBACK" }),
    toggleHelp: () => dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_HELP" }),
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FeedbackButton, HelpButton);
```

I'm getting an error when trying to `connect` the two components.  Is there a pattern that I could use to add the two components to state without using separate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upadate

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FeedbackButton, HelpButton);
```

to:

```
export const FeedbackButtonConnected = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FeedbackButton)
export const HelpButtonConnected = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(HelpButton)
```

And using it like this:

```
import { FeedbackButtonConnected,  HelpButtonConnected } from "path-to-file"
```